# Python OpenCv parse progress bar

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

**UPD: Added working MWE.**

I am trying to parse the amount of HP iт the game. The idea that I know the width of image and just get the width of filled part of the HP bar. And then just calculate it.

Previously it worked well. But recently game got some update and the **color is changed. I know. Just a color**.

Here is my fully **worked MWE code**: You can try it with sourcr files **attached in the end of the post**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def parse_hp(hp_area):
    width = int(hp_area.shape[1] * 5)
    height = int(hp_area.shape[0] * 5)
    dim = (width, height)

    # resize image
    resized = cv2.resize(hp_area, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    # Color segmentation
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_red = np.array([0, 50, 50])
    upper_red = np.array([5, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(resized, resized, mask=mask)

    # Contour exctraction
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (5, 5), 0)
    ret, thresholded = cv2.threshold(blurred, 50, 255, 0)
    contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresholded, 1, 2)

    if contours:
        cnt = contours[0]
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 25:  # to discard noise from the color segmentation
            contour_poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 3, True)
            center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour_poly)

            cv2.circle(resized, (int(center[0]), int(center[1])), int(radius), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.imshow("Found limits", resized)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

            resized_width = int(resized.shape[1])
            hp_width = radius * 2

            return int(hp_width * 100 / resized_width)
    else:
        return -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hp_area = cv2.imread("/Users/vetalll/Documents/Cv2Working.png")
    result = parse_hp(hp_area)
    print(result)
```

I tried to use these values. But it dos not work. openCv does not recognize them:

```
lower_red = np.array([355, 44, 45])
upper_red = np.array([356, 41, 43])
```

And now the color is a little bit purple.I know **that it uses HSV color** but really not able to figure aout how to adjust it to make it work. |

Working image:
[image: Working]

Not working image:
[image: Not working]

Source images can be grabbed here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dJ4ePw_7oJov_OU5n6IO6fwdm_N3W5k2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide an MWE?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't run the code without sample data. What I would need is that you reduce your code to only the necessary parts, so that I can run it myself.

Comment: The lower and upper color in code is given in BGR while your specified new colors are hsv. Use color code RGB2HSV instead of BGR2RGB and divide the first channel of your new range by 2

Comment: @mapf I just added MWE as you asked.. Please check it

Comment: Ok, so your problem is that before with the "old", you were able to find the contours, but now, with the "new" colors, it doesn't work anymore. Is that the issue? And the color scheme changed for some reason, but now you want to change the colors back to the way they were, yes?

Comment: @mapf Yes. this code works with image "Cv2Working.png" but i need to make it work with another. The difference only in color. But i am nt able to figure out how to adjust colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of guessing, I came up with these values. Hope they work:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def parse_hp(hp_area):
    width = int(hp_area.shape[1] * 5)
    height = int(hp_area.shape[0] * 5)
    dim = (width, height)

    # resize image
    resized = cv2.resize(hp_area, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    # Color segmentation
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    lower_red = np.array([120, 170, 0])
    upper_red = np.array([245, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(resized, resized, mask=mask)

    # Contour exctraction
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (5, 5), 0)
    ret, thresholded = cv2.threshold(blurred, 50, 255, 0)
    contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresholded, 1, 2)

    if contours:
        cnt = contours[0]
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 25:  # to discard noise from the color segmentation
            contour_poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 3, True)
            center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour_poly)

            cv2.circle(resized, (int(center[0]), int(center[1])), int(radius), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.imshow("Found limits", resized)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

            resized_width = int(resized.shape[1])
            hp_width = radius * 2

            return int(hp_width * 100 / resized_width)
    else:
        return -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hp_area = cv2.imread("Cv2NotWorking.png")
    result = parse_hp(hp_area)
    print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: And it works!! Thanks a lot. 
Could you tell me how did you determine these values?

Comment: First I used Inkscape (probably not the best tool but the one I'm most familiar with) to look at the HSV values of the new health bar, and then I had a look at what `cv2.inRange` does. From there on, I just started guessing HSV ranges. Most of it was just trial and error. If you are more familiar with HSV (which I'm not), it's probably pretty easy to guess the right values.

Comment: @mapf  Would it be feasible for that to work but taking into consideration that upper_red and lower_red may not have static RGB values - for example due to an animation of subtracting HP value the color changes but it is still considered "red", maybe a little more glowing etc